# libgdx's game, Screen Delay when switch from background to foreground on android

Tags: libgdx, screen

When I press the home key and return to my game, a black screen occurs.

I read online that is because textures are lost.

So, I want to know how to keep the texture valid when I resume the game. Are there any reasons for the problem? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally,There are two reasons for this problem.
Firstly,The resource of Texture have been disposed.
Secondly,You have load repeated resources.

My problem is the second problem.
Because I always create new world in Screen's show method.

My solution,I just need to judge whether the world is null.
I only need create the world when it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply (as an answer), you can check if the world is null *by checking if it's null*.

```
public void resume() {
    If(world == null) { 
        System.out.println("world is null");
        // create world
     } else {
        // do stuff when it's not null.
     }
}
```

Of course you can reference the `world` by making it `public static` when you declare it in play state so you can use it in your core code that `extends the ApplicationAdapter`.

Edit: Running some tests, I guess you need to set `world = null;` after calling `world.dispose;` in the `dispose()` method.